# How to add range of collection to other collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to make a list of unique entries.
I have two lists, but I would like to end up with one after checking if any entry is already in it. How could I realize this with Linq?

```
//Is a list with Activity, which have an ID property
public static List<Activity> Activites = new List<Activity>();

//Is only a list of string IDs
List<string> l = FileManagement.GetFileContent_List(WALLFILE);

foreach(Activity a in Activites) 
{
    if (!l.Contains(a.ID.ToString())) l.Add(a.ID.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `AddRange`, unless you need some more restrictions. Look into `Except` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Union method to concatenate all ID's and without duplicates:

```
l = l.Union(Activities.Select(a => a.ID.ToString()).ToList();
```

Or directly:

```
var l = FileManagement.GetFileContent_List(WALLFILE)
       .Union(Activities.Select(a => a.ID.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Union` will merge your lists together and won't duplicate values. For example:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>()
{
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "cat"
};

List<string> list2 = new List<string>()
{
    "dog",
    "cat", //extra
    "ear"
};

var combined = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

This will output

```
apple
banana
cat
dog
ear
```

You will need some way to compare a Activity to a string in `l`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the items you could try this:

```
var listA = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c", "a"};
var listB = new List<string>();
listB.AddRange(listA
   .Where(listAItem => listAItem != listB.Find(listBItem => listBItem == listAItem)));
```

This will return `listB { "a", "b", "c" };`